# Getting SSL Handshake error for the requests sent to vertex ai endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

We deployed our vector index which consists of 17 million word embeddings to an endpoint with a minimum number of replicas of 2 and
a maximum number of replicas of 6. 6 requests are sent to this endpoint at the same time using 6 threads.
Each request contains 10 queries. Sometimes after several requests, we get the SSL Handshake error I shared below.
We had numerous conversations with the Google Support team. There is no clue in the endpoint logs about the root cause of this error.
The IP address shown in the error does not belong to our system. In one of our conversations with Google, a developer stated that
this IP address belonged to one of the front-end servers on GCP. We also requested that the logs from that front-end server be shared with us,
but our request was not fulfilled. Google's guess is that Cisco Umbrella blocks the endpoint's public domain URL.
We confirmed that this domain is allowed in the Cisco umbrella and firewall logs.
This error occurs suddenly for no reason while the program is running properly.
After the error occurs, similar requests made to other endpoints in the same environment also fails with the same error.
We send these requests from the on-premise server. After this error starts to appear, it goes away on its own within 1 or 2 days,
and then we can continue using the endpoint. While the requests we make using Python SDK from the on-premise server fail,
we can perform vector search with the curl command in GCP's own console.
However, when we run the same curl command on the on-premise server, we get the SSL Handshake error again.
The Google team recommended us to use the REST API instead of the Python SDK, but once SSL error starts to appear,
same error is seen in the requests we send using curl or postman. It doesn't matter if I am connected to Cisco VPN or outside of VPN.
Even requests I make from my personal computer fail in the same way.
The Google team suggested us to use VPC network as a last solution, but this method requires too many architectural changes for us.
I would like to get different opinions on this subject. Have you ever encountered the same or similar situation before?

We are using the Vertex AI Python SDK for nearest neighbor search as described in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/vector-search/query-index-public-endpoint#python).

SSL Handshake Error logs:

```
E1214 12:45:07.871310736 3583475 ssl_transport_security.cc:1511\]       Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/appl/iapps/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 75, in error_remapped_callable
return callable\_(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/appl/iapps/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/\_channel.py", line 1161, in __call__
return \_end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
File "/appl/iapps/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/\_channel.py", line 1004, in \_end_unary_response_blocking
raise \_InactiveRpcError(state)  # pytype: disable=not-instantiable
grpc.\_channel.\_InactiveRpcError: \<\_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
details = "failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:34.110.189.138:443: Ssl handshake failed: SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE"
debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:34.110.189.138:443: Ssl handshake failed: SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE {grpc_status:14, created_time:"2023-12-14T12:45:07.871675797-05:00"}"
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/appl/iapps/deploy/abstract_json_generation/indexSearch.py", line 132, in getFromVertexAI
response = vertex_ai_client.find_neighbors(request)
File "/appl/iapps/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform_v1beta1/services/match_service/client.py", line 521, in find_neighbors
response = rpc(
File "/appl/iapps/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 131, in __call__
return wrapped_func(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/appl/iapps/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 77, in error_remapped_callable
raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:34.110.189.138:443: Ssl handshake failed: SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE```
````

Comment: Can you add a diagram and better format for people to understand how to reproduce.